# Django aggregate average of an annotation sum (1.6.5)

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset, django-1.6

---

Currently trying to grab an average of a sum of a group by, but when I try to execute the correct queryset it complains of incorrect syntax

```
objs = MyModel.objects.filter(...).values('user', 'value')
objs = objs.annotate(sum=Sum('value')) 
# i've also tried adding `.values('sum')` to the above
objs = objs.aggregate(Avg('sum')) # whines here
```

Is there any way to do this without dropping in SQL? The desired SQL is along the lines of

```
SELECT AVG(`sum`) as `avg` FROM ( 
    SELECT SUM(`appname_mymodel`.`value`) AS `sum`
    FROM `appname_mymodel` 
    GROUP BY 
        `appname_mymodel`.`user_id`, `appname_mymodel`.`value`
) as subquery ORDER BY NULL;
```

Not sure if django plays well with subqueries.

Here is the error message:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (SELECT SUM(`appname_mymodel`.`value`) AS `sum` FROM `appname_' at line 1")
```

**Django version** - 1.6.5

**MySQL version** - 5.5

Notes:

- If I leave off the `values` (the group by), it works fine (i.e. `objs.filter(...).annotate(...).aggregate(...)`
- The example below is sufficient as a fully reproducible example.

Model:

```
# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class OtherFK(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Happens if value is CharField or IntegerField
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    other_fk = models.ForeignKey(OtherFK)
```

Example:

```
>>> from app_name.models import UserProfile, OtherFK, MyModel
>>> up = UserProfile.objects.create(name="test")
>>> fk = OtherFK.objects.create(name="test")
>>> v1 = MyModel.objects.create(user=up, other_fk=fk, value="12", date="2015-10-01")
>>> v2 = MyModel.objects.create(user=up, other_fk=fk, value="13", date="2015-10-02")
>>> from django.db.models import Sum,Avg
>>> MyModel.objects.all().values("user").distinct().annotate(sum=Sum("value")).aggregate(Avg('sum'))
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `app_name_mymodel`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, SUM(`app_name_m' at line 1")
>>> MyModel.objects.all().values("user").distinct().annotate(sum=Sum("value"))
[{'sum': 25.0, 'user': 1L}]
>>> print MyModel.objects.all().values("user").distinct().annotate(sum=Sum("value")).query
SELECT DISTINCT `app_name_mymodel`.`user_id`, SUM(`app_name_mymodel`.`value`) AS `sum` FROM `app_name_mymodel` GROUP BY `app_name_mymodel`.`user_id` ORDER BY NULL
```

Comment: Why the `.values()`? I think that could be the problem, try removing it. -> `MyModel.objects.filter(...).annotate(sum_=Sum('value')).aggregate(Avg('sum_'))`

Comment: @Gocht I need to have the average of the sums at the grouped level, i.e. the average of the sums per user.

Comment: You need to use `.values()` to group the results right? That's the first one, why the second `.values()`?

Comment: I should have mentioned it happens with or without the second `.values()`

Comment: The sum per user is doing right?

Comment: @Gocht yeah with or without the second `values()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a [known bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23669#comment:5) in Django 1.6, and need to upgrade to 1.7+ to fix

For now, I will just do the math in python.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need, please give a feedback after test the line below:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(...).values('user__id').distinct().annotate(sum=Sum('value')).aggregate(Avg('sum'))
```

Comment: Still getting a programming error. `ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `appname_mymodel `.`user_id` AS `user_id`, SUM(`ap' at line 1")`

Comment: @C.B. Show your model please.

Comment: Added a watered down aliased version.

Comment: @C.B. I edited the answer, note `user__id` instead of `user_id` and, why are you trying to `Sum` a `CharField` ?

Comment: data is inherently an integer, just is stored as a char right now. `user` or `user__id` both fail with the same programming error. Again, the sum works fine.

Comment: I understand you hide some part of your code, such as names, but I think something important is being missing there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93738/discussion-between-gocht-and-c-b).